# array_splice 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Имеется массив в 32 ячейки, в каждой из которой есть массив с ценами неопределенной длины. Сам массив берётся из CSV-файла с помощью fgetcsv. Скрипт выдает 502 в этом куске кода:

```
$length = 1;
for($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
    foreach($list[$i]['prices'] as $key => $value) {
        sort($list[$i]['prices'][$key]);
        if(count($list[$i]['prices'][$key]) > $length) {
            array_splice($list[$i]['prices'][$key], $length);
        }
    }
}
```

Если заменить число в переменной $length на большее - скрипт работает. Но нужно оставлять в массиве только одну ячейку.

Весь массив: http://csgodone.ru/array.txt

Comment: @Bookin, мне нужно оставить в массиве $list[$i]['prices'] только 1 ячейку, так как дальше весь массив обрабатывается.

Comment: Не так переменную прочел)

Comment: Можете привести пример вашего массива $list?

Comment: @Bookin, весь массив: http://csgodone.ru/array.txt, слишком большой и не смог залить на pastebin.

Comment: @chaot1c, попробуйте вместо `array_splice($list[$i]['prices'][$key], $length);` использовать `$list[$i]['prices'][$key] = array_slice($list[$i]['prices'][$key], 0, $length);`

Comment: @Visman, не помогло, раньше использовал вместо splice точь-в-точь ваш вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Вашу ошибку не могу повторить

[В качестве примера:](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/64bc198f2c0d46f4f0bb18b80afaa279400ce5db)

```
$list = [
    0=>[
        'prices'=>[
            'Закаленное в боях'=>[
                0=>[1,2],
                1=>[2,3]
            ],
            'Поношенное'=>[
                0=>[3,4],
                1=>[1]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    1=>[
        'prices'=>[
            'Закаленное в боях'=>[
                0=>[1,2],
                1=>[2,3]
            ],
            'Поношенное'=>[
                0=>[3,4],
                1=>[1]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    2=>[
        'prices'=>[
            'Закаленное в боях'=>[
                0=>[1,2],
                1=>[2,3]
            ],
            'Поношенное'=>[
                0=>[3,4],
                1=>[1]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    3=>[
        'prices'=>[
            'Закаленное в боях'=>[
                0=>[1,2],
                1=>[2,3]
            ],
            'Поношенное'=>[
                0=>[3,4],
                1=>[1]
            ]
        ]
    ],
];

foreach($list as &$item){
    foreach($item['prices'] as $k=>$value){
        sort($value);
        if(count($value) > 1) {
            $item['prices'][$k]=$value[0];
        }
    }
}

var_dump($list);
```

Comment: Если использовать маленький массив, то 502 не будет, ошибка появляется при больших данных.

Comment: попробовал перенести на 16-поточную машину, все равно 502, грузит только 1 поток.